# Python: How do I sort array X but carry the same relative sort over to Y?

Tags: python, sorting

For example

```
X=[5,6,2,3,1]
Y=[7,2,3,4,6]
```

I sort X:

```
X=[1,2,3,5,6]
```

But I want the same relative sort applied to Y so the numbers stay in the same positions relative to each other as before:

```
Y=[6,3,4,7,2]
```

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, you do a `zip`-`sort`-`unzip` for this

```
>>> X = [5,6,2,3,1]
>>> Y = [7,2,3,4,6]
```

Now sort them together:

```
>>> sorted(zip(X,Y))
[(1, 6), (2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 7), (6, 2)]
```

Pair that with a "unzip" (`zip(*...)`)

```
>>> zip(*sorted(zip(X,Y)))
[(1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (6, 3, 4, 7, 2)]
```

which you could unpack:

```
>>> X,Y = zip(*sorted(zip(X,Y)))
>>> X
(1, 2, 3, 5, 6)
>>> Y
(6, 3, 4, 7, 2)
```

Now you have `tuple` instead of `list` objects, but if you really need to, you can convert it back.

---

As pointed out in the comments, this does introduce a very slight dependence on the second list in the sort:  Consider the lists:

```
X = [1,1,5,7] #sorted already
Y = [2,1,4,6] #Not already sorted.
```

With my "recipe" above, at the end of the day, you'll get:

```
X = (1,1,5,7)
Y = (1,2,4,6)
```

which might be unexpected.  To fix that, you could pass a `key` argument to `sorted`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
X,Y = zip(*sorted(zip(X,Y),key=itemgetter(0)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> X
[1, 1, 5, 7]
>>> Y
[2, 1, 4, 6]
>>> XX,YY = zip(*sorted(zip(X,Y)))
>>> XX
(1, 1, 5, 7)
>>> YY
(1, 2, 4, 6)
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> XX,YY = zip(*sorted(zip(X,Y),key=itemgetter(0)))
>>> XX
(1, 1, 5, 7)
>>> YY
(2, 1, 4, 6)
```

Comment: Note that this could change the order slightly (duplicate values will be in a sub-order from the second element, not in input order).

Comment: I might have duplicates in my list -- are you saying this wouldn't work in that case? One my of arrays is numeric, the other has strings (I assumed that there was a way to just take the general sorting approach from one list and apply it to the other)

Comment: @KaliMa -- The question is what order should the second object have if you have duplicates in the first list?  This solution will order the second elements in a "sorted" way, rather than keeping the order they had in the original list.

Comment: Note that it's easy to fix by using `sorted(..., key=itemgetter(0))` if you don't want the extra sorting.

Comment: @Lattyware -- I was writing that up as you were commenting apparently.

Answer (score 4):

Another idea:

```
>>> d = dict(zip(Y, X))
>>> sorted(Y, key=d.get)
[6, 3, 4, 7, 2]
```

You just use corresponding values in `X` as keys while sorting `Y`.

Comment: Doing it this way, there's no way to handle the situation where `Y` has duplicates.  It also enforces hashability of the elements in `Y`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to preserve order even if there are duplicate items:

```
def argsort(seq):
    '''
    >>> seq = [1,3,0,4,2]
    >>> index = argsort(seq)
    [2, 0, 4, 1, 3]

    Given seq and the index, you can construct the sorted seq:
    >>> sorted_seq = [seq[x] for x in index]
    >>> assert sorted_seq == sorted(seq)

    Given the sorted seq and the index, you can reconstruct seq:
    >>> assert [sorted_seq[x] for x in argsort(index)] == seq
    '''
    return sorted(range(len(seq)), key=seq.__getitem__)

X = (1,1,5,7)
Y = (1,2,4,6)
index = argsort(X)
print([Y[i] for i in index])
```

yields

```
[1, 2, 4, 6]
```

---

Regarding speed, `using_argsort` appears to be faster than `using_zip` or `using_dict`:

```
def using_argsort():
    index = argsort(X)
    return [X[i] for i in index], [Y[i] for i in index]

def using_zip():
    return zip(*sorted(zip(X,Y), key = operator.itemgetter(0)))

def using_dict():
    d = dict(zip(Y,X))
    return sorted(X), sorted(Y, key = d.get)

X = [5,6,2,3,1]*1000
Y = [7,2,3,4,6]*1000

In [18]: %timeit using_argsort()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit using_zip()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.65 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit using_dict()
100 loops, best of 3: 2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Of course this only works for objects which define a `__getitem__` and `__len__` method, but that's a common enough case that I'm happy to upvote this one. (+1).  Good solution.

Comment: I would argue that doing it by index makes it ugly - it means it won't work with more stuff and probably makes it slower.

Comment: Regarding the timing, this solution as well as the `dict` solution only compute the amount of time to sort the `Y` iterable.  Since OP mentioned sorting `X` as well, I imagine that adding an additional sort to both would be a more fair comparison -- That's linear for you, but O(n*log(n)) for the `dict` solution.

Comment: @mgilson: Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the functions and re-did the timings to make the comparison more fair.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming x and y have the same number of elements. when sorting x, everytime you swap two value, say, x.swap(i,j), you do y.swap(i,j) as well. By the way, I don't know python so this is not python syntax.