# Matplotlib issue: plt.plot(x,y, '.r-') connects each point from origin instead of with each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
x = [Timestamp ('03-01-2011 00:00:00'), Timestamp ('09-01-2014 00:00:00'), ... ]

y = [144, 23, ...]

plt.plot(x, y, '.r')
plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o', linestyle = '--')
```

[image]

What it looks like during plt.plot(x, y, '.r'), scatterplot only.

[image]

What it looks like when I add lines...

Datatypes:
x = timestamps from 2008 - 2014.
y = integer value at each time stamp.

How do I connect the scatterplot from point to point instead of connecting them all from origin?

Comment: You could show your code.

Comment: x = [Timestamp ('03-02-2011 00:00:00'), Timestamp ('09-04-2014 00:00:00', ...]

y = [114, 24, ... ]

plt.plot(x, y, '.r')  #first figure
plt.plot(x, y, '.r-') #second figure

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43620687/edit) your post and add your code

Comment: Also you have not put your question.

Comment: yea, I mean usually plt.plot(x,y) connects them from point to point... I dont know why its connecting at the origin

Comment: what is Timestamp ?

Comment: Your data must be sorted in ascending order along x axis.

Comment: Wow. Great catch. It was from not sorting the timestamps... Thanks !!

Comment: The points are connected by the order they are given. If you want adjacent time stamps connected to one another you should order them. You can use [`x, y = zip(*sorted(zip(x, y)))`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954912/python-how-do-i-sort-array-x-but-carry-the-same-relative-sort-over-to-y) to order them while keeping the x and y values corresponding correctly.

Comment: Thank guys, this issue has been resolved!